# Передача JSON на фронт. Как правильно?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Всем привет.
Вопрос:
У меня есть бэк на C# (Asp.net core) и фронт JS Vue.

На бэк я закидываю архив, внутри которого лежа JSON файлы.
Мне нужно этот архив распаковать, и данные откправить на фронт.

Вот тут вопрос.
Как правильно отправлять эти данные ?
Как файлы JSON и на фронте их как-то читать, или же читать их на бэке и отдавать на фронт толькь сам секст.

Дальше этои JSON мне нужно иметь возможность редактировать на фронте. (с возвратом корректировок на бэк).

С распаковкой архивов я разобрался, а вот что дальше делать концептуально с файлами не понимаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну обновлять вы их как планируете? Вот, допустим, вы уже отдали файл как то на фронт, он его поправил и хочет сохранить. Что ему делать? Куда и какой запос слать?

Comment: Мне тоже предстоит решать вопрос файлового обмена между беком и фронтом в ASP.Net я предварительно погуглил и понял что вопрос достаточно сложный. Планирую начать https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#uploading-large-files-with-streaming

Comment: @tym32167 ну я думаю так... Данные будут при загрузке сохраняться в БД. Сам изначальный архив изменяться не будет. Т.е. мы грузим данные из архива, они копируются в БД. Дальше фронт по Id пользователя кидает запрос, видит, что есть в БД данные, а  значит нужно выдать те данные, с которыми еще не закончена работа. Если данных нет, то грузится новый архив и БД с работаем с ним.
Соответственно дальше при изменении содержимого JSON мы меняем данные в БД. Как-то так, навенное

Comment: Попробуйте шаг за шагом описать что делает юзер, что он открывает, какие страницы, какие кнопки жмет, какое конкретно данные параметры едут при этом на сервер и как сервер конкретно это обрабатывает. Например, кто и как грузит данные? Это через интерфейс происходит? Кто имееет к этому доступ? Как схема бд выглядит? Как по ид юзера можно получить документы? Какая привязка юзера к документам в бд? Что значит «не закончена работа»? Кто это определяет и как эта информация хранится?

Comment: Ну и как выглядит интерфейс редактирования джейсона? Какие там надо валидации? Что если юзер ошибся в редактировании, надо делать возможность отката версии или перераспаковки из архива? Что значит «если данных нет»? Что такое «грузится новый архив»? Кем и куда грузится? Какие либо ограничения по размеру архива? Должен ли он немедленно распаковываться? Что если ошибки в распаковке или в архиве файлы не те?